# Cronjob doesn't find my script

Tags: cron

I've got an Ubuntu dedicated machine and I have to create a cronjob that runs my script at 3 am every day. When I try to make the cronjob it just gives me an error that the file couldn't be found, but it's directly there... I've tried to run it with PATH= in the crontab (commented 1st line) and without a path in the "command" part of the crontab.

Am I missing something?

The script is currently in /root/

Crontab: (don't mind the hour, testing purposes) http://prntscr.com/ecivq0

Error in the mail: http://prntscr.com/eciwkw

Update:
Result of the ls from the comments: pastebin.com/5xvq79cN

Comment: Could you please update your question with the output of `ls -l /root/backup.sh`

Comment: **Please don't use pictures for text**.  Please edit your question and place the text into your question.  Pictures are useful when copying and pasting text isn't available.  The text output in your question is very valuable.  The site itself will use that text to associate your question with suggestions of other threads that has similar text.  Also it makes easier on use to copy and paste from that text when we are performing research to help with the issue.  It's also much easier to read the text which fits nicely with our computer's fonts and size.

Comment: pastebin.com/5xvq79cN    I will update the question when i get the chance to connect to my server. Sorry.